# Accessing html elements from knockout view models

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, knockout.js, typescript

I've created a knockout component that wraps a bootstrap modal dialog, which I'm registering and loading (as an AMD module) as follows:

```
// Register dialogs as components
ko.components.register('create-user-dialog', {
    viewModel: { require: 'Features/Users/Index/CreateController' },
    template: { require: 'text!Features/Users/Index/CreateDialog.html' }
});
```

The template HTML contains a tag like:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="create-user-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
...
</div>
```

And the knockout view model extends a base class and looks like this (typescript):

```
export = CreateController

class CreateController extends Controllers.BootstrapModalController {

    constructor() {
        super($('#create-user-modal'));
    }
}

class BootstrapModalController {
    public dialog: JQuery;

    constructor(dialog: JQuery) {
        // Save a reference to the modal element so we can 
        // show/hide the dialog from the controller
        this.dialog = dialog;
    }

    // Show the modal window
    showModal = () => {
        this.dialog.modal({
            show: true,
            backdrop: 'static'
        });
    }

    // Close the modal window
    closeModal = () => {
        this.dialog.modal('hide');
    }
}
```

Finally, I use the component in my page as follows:

```
<div data-bind="component: 'create-user-dialog'"></div>
```

This works, but it's a bit messy since the `CreateController` does something I consider a bit strange in the constructor - namely using a jquery selector which tightly couples it with the html in the template.

To some extent, this is unavoidable, but I think it could be a bit nicer. If possible, I'd like the `BootstrapModalController` base class to be able to automatically determine the DOM element corresponding to the Bootstrap modal... that way `showModal` and `closeModal` would work, as long as the template actually contained a bootstrap modal dialog and descendants wouldn't have to explicitly pass in ids or jquery objects in the constructor.

I figured it might be able to use something like the [jQuery find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method to hunt for an element with the CSS class `modal` in the component's HTML template. However in order to do that I need to be able to get the rootNode that Knockout binds the component's view model against (i.e. the `<div data-bind="component: 'create-user-dialog'"></div>` element).

Is there any way to work out the html rootNode for a component from within the javascript view model for that component?

Comment: Handling the binding between a view and a viewmodel is the responsibility of bindingHandlers in the knockout world. My suggestion is that your ViewModel could have a property, named `isVisible` or similar, and that you create a bindingHandler for the modal, binding to that property. The bindingHandler is provided both the (potentially observable) value you bind to (from the ViewModel) as well as the element on which the bindingHandler is applied. Only the bindingHandler knows the API to the bootstrap DOM manipulation, instead of letting the ViewModel have this knowledge.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I think I found a solution along the lines of what you're talking about. So basically if you want to push stuff between the viewmodel and the dom (in either direction) a binding handler is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom binding, as described in the http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html article in order to wrap HTML/JS elements with Knockout, e.g. jquery button binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqButton = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = valueAccessor() || {};
        $(element).button(options);
    }
};
```

usage:

```
data-bind="jqButton: { ...some options... }"
```

In the custom binding you can access the element the binding is applied to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... it's not quite what I wanted though (what I wanted was the opposite - injecting references to DOM elements into the view model... not pushing view model stuff out to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

OK so the answer appears to be to use binding handlers. I found [this snippet](http://ox.no/posts/binding-a-dom-element-to-an-observable-using-knockout-js), which appears to do what I want:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.element = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
      var value = valueAccessor();
      value(element);
    }
};
```

Which the author demonstrates:

```
<canvas width="100" height="60" data-bind="element: yourObservable"></canvas>
```

All seems to work fairly painlessly... about the only thing is that in my case I have to create a JQuery object from the element as so:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.element = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
      var value = valueAccessor();
      value($(element));
    }
};
```

Thanks for the tips Robert!

Comment: You can also pass current element to the model via "$element" context property: data-bind="someBinding: { someParameter: $element}". I'm not sure this will work for components.

Comment: I prefere custom binding because of markup should depend on the model, not otherwise. Passing element to model brokes MVVM concept IMO ;).

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgement, but that is not what I suggested. :) I agree with @TSV that you should avoid pushing DOM elements into the ViewModel. BindingHandlers exist to handle the binding between the DOM and ViewModels. This would keep the dependency in the direction of View having a dependency on the ViewModel instead of also the ViewModel having a dependency on the View (DOM). Given your approach of pushing the DOM element into a property on the ViewModel, your ViewModel gets a dependency on the View (DOM), which makes it a lot harder to test.

Comment: That's true, but the methods in the view model are showModal and closeModal... Given the nature of those methods, I think some dependency on the view is unavoidable. I guess not **all** use cases are going to be easily testable using stuff like jasmine and unit tests... this is probably one of those cases where protractor and regression tests are going to be necessary.

Comment: @JamesCrosswell You can easily have the showModal and closeModal methods just set an observable bool property `isShowingModal`. That way the bindingHandler can just bind to that bool property and show/hide the modal based on the value. If you would like it, I can write an example of what I mean as an answer. Just let me know.